# concrete blocks

Tags: concrete, walls, structural, building

can you use the large interlocking concrete blocks(1600mmx800mmx800mm) to build a house? Would you use extra cement or would you it be safe and strong with the right structure to withstand hurricanes? Without any cement the building could be made quickly.

Comment: There are systems that are dry fit and then joints grouted to seal. Google Dac-Art. http://www.dac-art.com/

Comment: I am not aware of any blocks that would not require mortar joints or being filled.